# Preference not working in Magento 2.4.4 enterprise edition

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento2.4.4

I want to override `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\CreateHandler` into the custom module.

Imgix/Magento/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\CreateHandler" 
                type="Imgix\Magento\Model\Product\Gallery\CreateHandler"/>
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\UpdateHandler"
                type="Imgix\Magento\Model\Product\Gallery\UpdateHandler" />
</config>
```

I need some modifications to execute the method.I have added some line after } `elseif (empty($image['value_id']) || !empty($image['recreate'])) {` line.

```
<?php

namespace Imgix\Magento\Model\Product\Gallery;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionInterface;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader as FileUploader;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityMetadata;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Gallery;
use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\CreateHandler as ProductGalleryCreateHandler;

class CreateHandler extends ProductGalleryCreateHandler
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Gallery $resourceModel
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config $mediaConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $fileStorageDb
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface|null $storeManager
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Gallery $resourceModel,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config $mediaConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $fileStorageDb,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager = null
    ) {
        $this->metadata = $metadataPool->getMetadata(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::class);
        $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
        $this->resourceModel = $resourceModel;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->mediaConfig = $mediaConfig;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->fileStorageDb = $fileStorageDb;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(StoreManagerInterface::class);
        parent::__construct(
            $metadataPool,
            $attributeRepository,
            $resourceModel,
            $jsonHelper,
            $mediaConfig,
            $filesystem,
            $fileStorageDb,
            $storeManager
        );
    }

    /**
     * Execute create handler
     *
     * @param object $product
     * @param array $arguments
     * @return object
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    public function execute($product, $arguments = [])
    {
        $attrCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();

        $value = $product->getData($attrCode);

        if (!is_array($value) || !isset($value['images'])) {
            return $product;
        }

        if (!is_array($value['images']) && strlen((string) $value['images']) > 0) {
            $value['images'] = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($value['images']);
        }

        if (!is_array($value['images'])) {
            $value['images'] = [];
        }

        $clearImages = [];
        $newImages = [];
        $existImages = [];
        if ($product->getIsDuplicate() != true) {
            foreach ($value['images'] as &$image) {
                if (!empty($image['removed']) && !$this->canRemoveImage($product, $image['file'])) {
                    $image['removed'] = '';
                }
                if (!empty($image['removed'])) {
                    $clearImages[] = $image['file'];
                } elseif (empty($image['value_id']) || !empty($image['recreate'])) {
                    if (strpos((string) $image['file'], 'imgix') !== false) {
                        $image['new_file'] = $image['file'];
                        $newImages[$image['file']] = $image;
                    } else {
                        $newFile = $this->moveImageFromTmp($image['file']);
                        $image['new_file'] = $newFile;
                        $newImages[$image['file']] = $image;
                        $image['file'] = $newFile;
                    }
                } else {
                    $existImages[$image['file']] = $image;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // For duplicating we need copy original images.
            $duplicate = [];
            foreach ($value['images'] as &$image) {
                if (!empty($image['removed']) && !$this->canRemoveImage($product, $image['file'])) {
                    $image['removed'] = '';
                }

                if (empty($image['value_id']) || !empty($image['removed'])) {
                    continue;
                }
                $duplicate[$image['value_id']] = $this->copyImage($image['file']);
                $image['new_file'] = $duplicate[$image['value_id']];
                $newImages[$image['file']] = $image;
            }
            $value['duplicate'] = $duplicate;
        }
        if (!empty($value['images'])) {
            $this->processMediaAttributes($product, $existImages, $newImages, $clearImages);
        }
        $product->setData($attrCode, $value);
        if ($product->getIsDuplicate() == true) {
            $this->duplicate($product);
            return $product;
        }
        if (!is_array($value) || !isset($value['images']) || $product->isLockedAttribute($attrCode)) {
            return $product;
        }
        $this->processDeletedImages($product, $value['images']);
        $this->processNewAndExistingImages($product, $value['images']);
        $product->setData($attrCode, $value);
        return $product;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why preference is not working?

**Note:** Above code is working fine with the Magento CE version.
Thanks

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: issue fixed now, in Enterprise edition Magento_CatalogStaging module confilct.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the above issue for the Magento EE and ECE versions. Just override `CreateHandler.php` and `UpdateHandler.php` files in `di.xml`

Imgix/Magento/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\CreateHandler" 
                type="Imgix\Magento\Model\Product\Gallery\CreateHandler"/>
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\UpdateHandler"
                type="Imgix\Magento\Model\Product\Gallery\UpdateHandler" />
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogStaging\Model\Product\Gallery\CreateHandler"
                type="Imgix\Magento\Model\Product\Gallery\CreateHandler" />
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogStaging\Model\Product\Gallery\UpdateHandler"
                type="Imgix\Magento\Model\Product\Gallery\UpdateHandler" />
</config>
```